# PHP on Apache on Linux: when web app starts processes, is it possible to keep those processes alive if Apache gets restarted?

Tags: php, linux, apache

We have a web app which allows us to monitor and control our server applications.  The web pages start applications by executing a shell script to start them.  The problem we have run into is that if we need to restart apache, it kills any of the processes that were started by the web app.

The web pages are PHP, and are using the `exec()` command to call the start scripts.  The start scripts start Java apps, and and run the apps with something like this:

`nohup java ... &`

As mentioned, PHP is running in Apache on Linux.  Is there some other switch or way to start these processes which would not have them be child processes of Apache (and killed when it stops)?

CLARIFICATION

I am more familiar with Windows than with Linux.  In Windows, if you want to accomplish what we are trying add the `start` keyword in the shell, i.e.:

```
start <batchfile>
```

When you use `start`, the new shell/process can be unhooked from the one that started it.  Is there a Linux equivalent to the `start` command?

Comment: `batch`  does the job on Linux that `start` seems to do on Windoiws.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: thanks, we'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [batch(1)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_batch.htm) to start your long lasting server processes.

In shell, you could do

```
batch << END
    java yourjava.jar
END
```

if you have some batch shell script file, start it with

```
batch -f yourbatchfile
```

If you can improve the Java programs, you might have them call [daemon(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/daemon) at their start time, perhaps using the [daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/) thing from Apache.

You probably want to store the daemons' process pid somewhere (e.g. in some file or database), to be able to stop them (first with `kill -TERM`, then with `kill -QUIT`, at last with `kill -KILL`).

Using `daemon` function or Java thing is probably better than using a `batch`

Comment: Thanks for the note.  We do already have the web pages look up the PID, and we can shut the processes down gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion about batch. We'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Starting long-lasting processes by PHP sounds like asking for big trouble.
You will have problems like yours, and you will have huge security implications.

Much better solution is to have your PHP pages save their intent that something needs to be run in batch mode into database table (MySQL or PostgreSQL).

Another process (probably running under more advanced credentials than apache www user) should run as daemon and constantly check database for new stuff to do and execute necessary tasks (also it could be fired by cron every few minutes).

This way, you will kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: These servers are internal application servers and not publicly accessible, and port 80 is firewalled by IP.  So the security concern is minimal (no more than the concern for who can access the server in any other respect).  We've had this set up for 5 years - so there is no big trouble in store.  We just want to solve this one problem.

Comment: Note that using PostgreSQL table LISTEN/NOTIFY mechanism, you can achieve virtually zero delay for request execution, and without constant polling

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up [how to create long running processes with php on my blog](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html) however I've got to agree with mvp that this approach is far from ideal for your purposes - not just from the point of view of privilege seperation (using a setuid program or sudo solves that easily enough).

Depending opn what you're trying to achieve here, I suspect that the additional functionality in DJ Bernsteins [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) will be a better fit.

Comment: The web pages are a control panel for the server applications.  It seems too indirect to introduce yet another process to handle the starting (and then we have another thing to monitor).  The web pages are really an on/off switch for other applications. I think it's a reasonable design goal to have them be able to turn on/off the process (virtually) synchronously.  Thanks also for recommendation to daemontools, we will check it out.

Comment: The daemontools is definitely the solution.